# Ruby - How do I make this program move to the next equation?

Tags: ruby

I'm just learning to program so this is a novice question.I'm trying to start really simple but can't get my head around this problem.

I'm writing a program that asks the user for an answer to a given equation. Like 8 times 9

The program is supposed to ask what is the answer to an equation, take a number (sum) as input from the user to answer what the equation is. If the user is correct, it is meant to say "Correct!" and add a point to their score. If the user is incorrect, it is meant do say "Incorrect, answer is: x" and generate another equation without adding a point to their score.

With the program as it is, this is what happens if the user is incorrect: [Incorrect answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1Ucr.png)

And this is what happens if the user is correct: [Correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baihg.png)

How do I make a loop that make the program move to the next equation? I've tried experimenting with different ways of doing it but I can't manage to get it.

Here is my code...

```
# Assigns random number to n1
n1 = rand(11)
# Assigns random number to n2
n2 = rand(11) 

# Puts together the equation
q = String(n1) + " times " + String(n2)

# Gets the answer ready
a = n1 * n2

# Self explanatory
gamesPlayed = 0
score = 0

# Asks for sum answer 
puts("What is " + q + "?") 

# Takes users guess
g = gets() 

#
# This is where I'm stuck
#

# This loop is supposed to make the game move onto the next equation
while Integer(g) == a
  puts("Correct!")
  # Supposed to add to the score
  score += 1
end
puts("Incorrect, answer is: " + String(a))
gamesPlayed += 1
# ^ Supposed to move to next equation

# Not sure if necessary - Supposed to make program stop after third question    
if gamesPlayed == 2
   gamesPlayed += 1
else
end

# Self explanatory
puts("Game over, you scored: " + String(score))
```

P.S. Any help on solving this and some constructive criticism on the code is much appreciated.
**UPDATE**

I changed the code to what was suggested, and it worked for the most part. Though there was still a problem, took me a long time to figure it out.

```
gamesPlayed = 0
score = 0

while gamesPlayed != 2
    n1 = rand(11)
    n2 = rand(11)
    a = n1 * n2
    q = String(n1) + " times " + String(n2)
    puts("What is " + q + "?")
    g = gets()
    if g == a # where the problem was
        puts("Correct!")
        score += 1
        gamesPlayed += 1
    else
        puts("Incorrect, answer is: " + String(a))
        gamesPlayed += 1
    end
end
puts("Game over, you scored: " + String(score))
```

I changed the if condition from `if g == a` to `if Integer(g) == a` , works now!

Comment: What next equation? There's only one equation, no next.

Answer (score 1):

So far you are only generating one equation, as rand() is only called once. You want to put it in the while loop. As a tip, if you are stuck, create a plan of what the steps you are trying to complete are, and then compare that to what your code is doing.

As for your code:

```
gamesPlayed = 0
score = 0

while gamesPlayed != 2
   n1 = rand(11)
   n2 = rand(11)
   a = n1*n2
   q = String(n1) + " times " + String(n2)
   puts("What is " + q + "?") 
   g = gets()
   if g == a
       puts("Correct!")
       score += 1
       gamesPlayed += 1
   else
       puts("Incorrect, answer is: " + String(a))
       gamesPlayed += 1
   end
end
puts("Game over, you scored: " + String(score))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response, I see what you're saying. I tried nesting the if condition inside a while loop but I see I was doing it incorrectly. However, the last line in your code.    `puts("Game over, you scored: " + String(score))` I get a syntax error when I run it: game.rb:19: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
puts("Game over, you scored: " + String(score)) What is the issue here?

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to add the final end statement for the while loop, and that is what the error was flagging. Try the amended code. It should work this time.